# Trigger change on elements/node list too slow

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have many checkboxes inside a div I want to reset. All of them have same event on change. When reset button is clicked, the current property and data-default is compared and if it is different the property is set to this value and change event is triggered.

Data-default is the checked state of the checkbox set on page load or when section is saved by ajax.

```
var $checkboxes = $section.find(":checkbox");

for (var i = 0; i < $checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var $cb = $($checkboxes[i]);

    var currentValue = $cb.prop("checked");
    var defaultValue = $cb.data("default");

    if (currentValue !== defaultValue) {
        $cb.prop("checked", defaultValue)
            .trigger("change");
    }
}
```

The problem here is performance. It takes around 1 sec to trigger change event with jquery for 70 checkboxes. And when there are 1000 checkboxes to be reset, it takes about 5 min (if browser doesn't crash).

Is there a better way to fire onchange event for array of objects, maybe with vanilla javascript?

Comment: When clicking on the reset button, you want the checkboxes to be all checked right?

Comment: @JuOliveira I'm resetting the value to dava-value property and then trigger change event for the ones with changed value.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem as if much is wrong with your code. Probably there is a performance bottleneck in your callback. You can do one thing. If you are using chrome, you can use the Chrome Profiler which will tell you exactly where your time is going. There is a performance tab in the developer tools which will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want all checkboxes to be checked when clicking on reset button.. I suggest using the [jQuery function `each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and simplify a little bit your code

I've been using this code to select all names in a contact list with a lot of checkboxes and it runs fast, hope it does the same for you!

```js
$('#reset-button').click(function() {
    
    // Search for each checkbox
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each( function(){
    
        // Verify if is checked
        $value = $(this).is( ":checked" );
        
        if( $value == false ){
           // If not checked, turns checkbox into checked state
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

```css
button {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="reset-button">Reset</button>


<div>
    <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
    <input type="checkbox" value="two" checked>2
    <input type="checkbox" value="three">3
    <input type="checkbox" value="four">4
    <input type="checkbox" value="five" checked>5
    <input type="checkbox" value="six" checked>6
    <input type="checkbox" value="seven" checked>7
    <input type="checkbox" value="eight">8
</div>
```

Comment: The actual problem is, triggering the "change event" on many checkboxes. Not resetting the checked property.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy I get that the problem is triggering the "change event", but having in account my little knowlege in Javascript/jQuery, it looks to me that you're doing a double 'setting/trigger' with this piece of code `$cb.prop("checked", defaultValue).trigger("change");` and that's why it's taking so long

Comment: @HasanGürsoy I can be really really wrong in what I just said, but try to remove the last part `.trigger("change")` and check if it's faster..

Comment: @HasanGürsoy And I asked about the checked property and wrote this snippet because it looks to me a little bit more simplified than the code you wrote, but don't take it in a bad way, I'm just trying to help :)

Comment: NP. Setting property checked programmatically of a checkbox doesn't trigger change. That is why I needed to trigger change event manually. I don't think the problem is related with the code. Rather than browser performance. I've already fixed the UI by replacing checkboxes groups with single multi select.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy Okay, thanks for the explanation and sorry that I couldn't help :/